# Why do I get App not Setup error when Facebook is integrated with my Android App?

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated Facebook in my Android Application. I am at present the administrator of my app . The problem is as follows:
When I click the Button on my app the FaceBook login page pops up. And I login with my email id(abc@gmail.com). After verification of my email and password, my activity page is displayed.

But if someone else installs this app on his/her phone and tries to login, the Facebook Login page pops up and after entering the id(xyz@gmail.com) they get a following error page displaying the following message:

Error:

App Not Setup.The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for FaceBook Login.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong. Please explain step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running the app in sandbox mode, meaning that only people that you allow can use your app. By default the admin can run they app using his/her credentials. You will need to either add people as developers, admins, or testers (there is an option in your app's settings page in Facebook to do this). If you want to add testers, the best thing to do is to create tester accounts (via your app's settings page on Facebook). You shouldn't use people's actual Facebook account as tester accounts because they will no longer have normal functionality after they become a tester.